# How to include autocomplete in a python web form with MongoDB

Tags: python, forms, autocomplete

I wrote a web page in Python as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import os, re, sys
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import Connection
import cgi

class Handler:
     def do(self, environ, start_response):
         html = "<html><head><title>C Informatics</title></head><body>"
         html += "<h1><center>National Management & Information System</h1>"    
         html += '<center><h3>CONTROL PROGRAMME<br>'
         html += '</center>'
         html += '<form method="post" action="newreg.py">' 
         html += 'Person Name :<input type="text" name="pname">'
         html += 'Age :<input type="text" name="age">'
         html += 'Gender : <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">M'
         html += '<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">F<br><br>'
         html += 'Complete Address :<br>'
         html += 'H.No. and Street :<input type="text" name="hn1">'
         html += 'Locality : <input type="text" name="locality">'  
         html += 'PIN Code : <input type="text" name="pin"><br>'   
         html += '<input type="submit" Value="Save">'
         html += '</form>'
         html += '</center>'
         html += "</body></html>"
         connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
         db = connection.health
         tc = db.testColl
         item = tc.find_one()["name"]
         html += str(item)
         html += name
         output = html
         mimeType = "text/html"
```

In the above form, I want to autocomplete the form field 'Location' (which also pulls out the respective PIN code of that location and displays in the field PIN).

The Data, Locations Name and their respective PIN code, are saved in a collection in MongoDB.

So that when 'Save' is clicked the information is saved in new collections in MongoDB.

With code, can some one please show me how it can be done ?

Thanks

NC

Answer (score 3):

This question has neither to do with Python nor with MongoDB. What you are trying is some auto-complete functionality through Javascript.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

is a good start.